# Удалить метку [учебное-задание]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Зачем нужна метка [учебное-задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)? Может быть лучше удалить её, дабы не вводить страждущих в искушение и ложное понимание назначения сайта?

Тем более, что описание метки говорит о том, что никто отвечать на вопросы с такой меткой не будет. Она действительно избыточна и вредна.

Не пора ли метку действительно удалить?

Comment: Апнул вопрос, он по-прежнему актуален.

Comment: @NickVolynkin существует какой-то модераторский инструмент для массового удаления меток?

Comment: @alexolut не встречал.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а возможность удалить саму метку? Т.е. не из вопросов (это будет уже следствием), а из списка всех меток.

Comment: @NickVolynkin тут правда возникает проблема вопросов с единственной меткой.

Comment: @alexolut можно только объединить, это когда все вхождения одной метки заменяются на другую.

Comment: @alexolut где-то есть доступный только разработчикам черный список меток, запрещающий использование в новых вопросах.

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно попробовать заменить автоматом на `алгоритм`. Это не совсем верно, но зато быстро убьет все метки. А потом любители алгоритмов уже выпилят ее из вопросов, где она не совсем уместна :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin тем не менее, кто-то в новый вопрос добавил `учебное-задание` недавно, иначе я бы на эту страницу не попал.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Метка [учебное-задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) появлялась на многих ресурсах в сети Stack Exchange, и была уничтожена тоже на всех. Пора избавляться от неё и нам.

На ресурсе *все* вопросы должны отвечать одним требованиям: чётко сформулированная задача вместе со всеми ограничениями; необходимое и реальное поведение в случае глюков; желательно примеры кода со своими попытками решения, которые позволяют понять, в чём именно загвоздка.

Если для ответа на вопрос требуется выяснить, относится ли вопрос к учебному заданию, то это плохой вопрос, и его нужно или закрыть, или заминусовать — и отсутствие или наличие метки тут совсем не при чём.

Кроме того, задачки с искусственными ограничениями не обязательно учебные. Это могут быть или "олимпиадные" задачки, или ограничения могут быть вызваны средой выполнения, или ещё что-то.

Подписавшийся на метку [учебное-задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) только один, из чего можно сделать вывод, что "специалистов" по этой метке нет, что является ещё одним признаком мета-метки.

Comment: 727 вопросов... тут нужно что-то получше, чем ручное удаление.

Comment: @Nofate Есть некий "чёрный список меток", и на большом СО, судя по всему, в него занесены эти все "учебное задание", "программирование", "интернет", "google" и прочие. Было бы замечательно, если бы Николас до этого чёрного списка добрался.

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что вы метку вычистили?

Comment: @NickVolynkin 670 вопросов. Что там вычищено-то?

Comment: @Discord: хех, это у меня вкладка «конкурсные» была открыта, не заметил. Мало ли, может с программированием заодно )

Answer (score -4):

Копия ответа со старой [Меты](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2551/).

---

Метка [учебное-задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) означает, что вопрос более академический нежели прикладной.

За счет своей академической направленности учебные задания зачастую могут быть очень интересны знатокам. Как минимум, это отличное средство держать знания в тонусе.

Comment: Не знаю, что такого "тонусного" в учебных заданиях. Обычно там оказываются вопросы "как реализовать X на коленке" с пометкой "чтобы прокатило в школе, а не чтобы работало нормально". Там оказываются вопросы "Мне задали написать X, чё делать-то? Нифига не понимаю в этих странных буковках :((((((((((" В общем и целом там практически нет вопросов, которые имеют для профессионалов хоть какую-то ценность. Там или "сделайте за меня" или "как написать велосипед", причём велосипед, как правило, банальной штуки, красно-чёрные деревья там не найдешь. / А в общем и целом это мета-метка.

Comment: Для этого есть метка "алгоритм". "Учебное-задание" мало у кого вызывает ассоциации с академичностью, я полагаю. Скорее с "сделайте мне на халяву!"