# "Неспортивное поведение" и стоит ли с ним бороться?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, ответы

**Описание проблемы:**

Я уже не раз был свидетелем событий (даже не смотря на то, что я новичек на вашем ресурсе), при которых один пользователь, который знает ответ на поставленный вопрос, во благо своего рейтинга (т.е. из корыстных побуждений), видя ответ другого пользователя на поставленный вопрос (и при этом ответ этого пользователя еще имеет 0-ой рейтинг, либо равный рейтингу ответа 2го пользователя, о котором сейчас идет речь), минусует его ответ и тут же отвечает сам, тем самым продвигая свой ответ вверх в общем списке (в соответствии с описанием в [начальном туре сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)), что потенциально повышает шансы его ответа на получение дальнейших положительных баллов, в отличие от ответа первого пользователя, т.е. если ответ первого пользователя изначально имел 0-ой рейтинг и после голоса конкурента ушел в минус, то повышается вероятность того, что часть пользователей, я бы даже сказал большая часть пользователей, будет уделять меньше внимания ответу с уже отрицательным рейтингом, нежели с чем на ответ с еще 0-ым рейтингом, т.е. поддадутся *инстинкту толпы*, а не компетентные пользователи могут еще и минусовать дальше.

К счастью, описанные выше события не коснулись напрямую меня (по крайней мере пока что), но лично меня огорчает такое поведение некоторых пользователей. Сразу оговорюсь, я не могу быть на 100% уверенным в том, что именно человек ответивший на вопрос вторым минусует ответ первого (по крайней мере я не нашел в интерфейсе данного ресурса способа определить это), но наблюдал именно такую тенденцию, при которой одновременно с появлением ответа от 2го пользователя, адекватный и правильный ответ 1го пользователя уходил в минус, что по крайней мере вызывает подозрения, согласитель?

Опять-таки, я говорю лишь о тех ситуациях, в которых я был компетентен и наверняка знал, что ответ 1го пользователя является верным, ровно как и ответ 2го. Лично я в таких ситуациях (когда прямо на глазах уходил в минус ответ 1го и появлялся ответ от 2го, который в итоге становился выше ответа 1го) поднимал ответ 1го. Я, все-таки, за *"спортивное поведение"*, плюсую даже если ответ дан одновременно со мной, но немного в другом русле и верный.

Таким образом, описанная проблема является прямой противоположность знака за [Спортивное поведение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship), хоть новый знак *Неспортивное поведение* вводи! Не обращайте внимания - это я так не смешно пошутил.

---

**Суть вопроса:**

Как стоит вести себя в таких ситуациях?
Например, я вижу несколько способов поведения:

1. игнорировать
2. попытаться спросить посредством комментариев к ответу, который минусанули, почему так происходит
3. отметить *"тревогой"* ответ, который минусанули (правда немного странно помечать именно его), и в пояснении к *"тревоге"* расписать сложившуюся ситуацию, а затем надеяться на рассудительного модератора, который среагирует на это должным образом (правда тогда у меня встает вопрос, а что может сделать модератор?)

1-го варианта лично мне придерживаться сложно, т.к. я сильно огорчаюсь в таких ситуациях (даже не смотря на то, что они не касаются непосредственно меня).
2-ой же вариант, я так понимаю, не является решением проблемы как таковым (по крайней мере учитывая лозунг данного ресурса `Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего.` и такие посты как [этот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2171/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)).
Если у вас имеются на примете иные способы поведения, то буду рад выслушать.

---

**P.S.**

На текущем ресурсе я совсем новичок, но мне нравится здешняя атмосфера и подход к решению проблем, поэтому хочется сделать хоть какой-нибудь вклад в направлении ресурса в идеалистическое русло.
Знаю, что не вышло лаконично описать проблему, но, согласитель, проблема не такая уж банальная, и думаю, что вы (по крайней мере некоторые из вас) сталкивались с ней хотя бы 1 раз. Надеюсь на вашу заинтересованность в решении данной проблемы :)

Comment: Вы бы ссылку на вопрос/ответ привели в котором как Вам кажется было *неспортивное* поведение

Comment: Мне кажется это не более, чем совпадение....Вы же понимаете, что на сайте находится не 3 человека, а намного больше? Соответственно за одно мгновение может произойти множество событий..... имхо все логично. Всё зависит от степени паранойи :-)

Comment: Это, кстати, распространённая проблема и на английском SO, там она называется _tactical downvoting_.

Comment: @Bald Дело в том, что я сталкивался с таким лишь пару раз и каждый раз после моего голоса в +, ответ приобретал 0-ой бал и в дальнейшем шел вровень с ответом 2го пользователя по балам, поэтому в данный момент такие ответы практически ничем не отличаются по балам.

Comment: Проблема, конечно, существует. Вряд ли она действительно серьезна и скорее всего, в рамках существующих правил и обеспечивающего их софта решения не имеет. Теоретически ее можно решить, запретив обезличенные минусы и обязав минусующего писать пояснительный комментарий. Но    это плохое решение, поскольку очевидно, что в таком случае даже в самом деле плохие вопросы-ответы вообще не будут минусоваться.

Comment: как вариант можно обязать написать комментарий пользователя, который оставил свой вопрос и при этом поставил минусы другим ответам в данном вопросе. Однако это будет ограничением свободы действий, да и слишком изворотливых это вряд ли остановит. На текущий момент почти ничего не сделано для блокировки данной проблемы. Но, если Вы наверняка уверены, что в отношении Вас был *tactical downvoting*, обсудите данную проблему по Вашему ответу с модераторами в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/).

Comment: ох уж эта борьба в грязи за плюсики

Comment: Зато вы почитайте переписку людей в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27614352#27614352) к ответу, отмеченному решением: они там отжигают местами :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Если Вы уверены, что против Вас был тактический downvoting, то воспользуйтесь одним из вариантов ниже:

- Напишите комментарий под ответом, в котором изложите просьбу объяснить минус. Однако помните, что очень редко кто поясняет свое голосование.
- Напишите жалобу модераторам в чате - они могут попросить пользователя пояснить за что был поставлен минус и вынести предупреждение. Виновник видя то, что его могут вычислить, возможно перестанет заниматься подобными делами впредь.
- Забудьте и двигайтесь дальше, делая мир лучше своими ответами. Чем больше Вы даете хороших ответов, тем лучше у Вас репутация и с течением времени, при большой репутации, возможно, Вы перестанете замечать такие проблемы.

*Ответ написан(и отчасти переведен/скопирован) после ознакомления с вопросом по [подобной проблеме на en so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6460/307712). Пользователь выявил тактический downvoting, в результате чего его ответ поддержали другие пользователи, а ответ виновника засыпали минусами.*

Comment: предлагаю перенести дискуссию в основной чат сайта. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27614910#27614910

Answer (score 11):

Если Вам позволяют знания оценить ответ и вы считаете что минус не заслуженный то можете его исправить своим плюсом, так же под ответом Вы можете написать комментарий с просьбой уточнить за что получен минус, вполне возможно что автор ответа либо другой более опытный участник прояснит за что был поставлен минус.

Если вопрос/ответ собрал большую *пачку* минусов, значит с ним не все нормально, а не сообщество поддалось *инстинкту*.

Привлекать внимания к таким вопросам/ответам всего сообщества мне кажется излишнем, хотя в некоторых случаях может быть уместно спросить в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)

Comment: Опять же, я упоминал лишь ситуации, когда я был компетентен и знал, что оба ответа верны (иногда они отличались лишь тем, что предожения были просто переформулированы). 1 раз видел даже как один из пользователей, владельцев такого неудачного ответа, в комментарии к собственному ответу спросил, что в его ответе именно не так, на что не получил никакого ответа (его вопрос просто проигнорировали). Я, конечно, понимаю, что это _"темная сторона"_ сообщества (которая, к счастью, проявляется очень редко), и никто не хочет её затрагивать, но, все-таки, нельзя же просто сказать, что такой проблемы нет.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive если кто то в погоне за рейтингом ставит минусы ответам конкурентам то это целиком и полностью на его совести

Answer (score 6):

Я считаю, что если целью ответа является получение баллов рейтинга, то отвечать вообще не стоит.

Идея о том, что хорошие ответы будут писать за баллы, хороша только в фантазиях.

В реальности же получается так, ничего не значащие виртуальные баллы "репутации" привлекают только человека с уровнем развития школьника, с предсказуемым результатом: хороший ответ на сложный вопрос не принесет репутации вообще (см. Bike Shed problem), в то время как для получения максимального количества баллов идеальной стратегией является написание максимально большого количества ответов на максимально примитивные вопросы (доступные пониманию такой же школоты, которая будет их оценивать).

В итоге, вместо воображаемого в розовых мечтах кладезя знаний, в реальности имеется засорение ресурса, которое можно наглядно обонять на английском SO.

Человека же, который может дать действительно полезный и хороший ответ, эти виртуальные фантики не интересуют от слова совсем. Мотивация должна быть другой.

Comment: Но если это единственный человек, который знает ответ, то не ответив он сделает хуже себе (тем, что не получит балы) и тому, кто задал вопрос (тем, что никто ему так и не ответит, либо не дадут развернутого и грамотного ответа). Поэтому с этой точки зрения, мне кажется нормальным то, что человек вознаграждается рейтингом за правильные ответы и его это может его подстегивать писать все более развернутые и доступные ответы (т.е. это даже хорошо).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Сюда приходят за получением знаний и за тем, чтобы ими поделиться. За повышением своей самооценки за счет ответа на миллион вопросов вида `чему равен x в уравнении 2x + 2 = 4` можно идти на другие лохо-быдло-ресурсы.... Если вам так нужны поощрения, конфеточки, что вы умничка - можно идти к мамочке.....Еще раз повторю: ресурс - чтобы поделиться знаниями. Они бесплатные должны быть и альтруистичные, а не ждать косточки, как собачёнка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я понимаю вашу точку зрения, но мне кажется, что просто вы не желаете даже попробовать принять чужую. Ведь вы в моих словах даже не рассмотрели то, что я не призываю к такому поведению, я лишь указываю на тот факт, что нужно смотреть на это со стороны выгодной для данного ресурса (это как если бы вы подскользнулись и упали - вы бы сразу сказали, что это однозначно плохо, хотя по факту, вы получили жизненный опыт и впредь будете аккуратнее ходить по льду), но, нет, вы в моих словах увидели именно то, что и хотели увидеть - это "не есть хорошо".

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нельзя смотреть на жизнь однобоко, я всего лишь стараюсь быть объективным (ну или по крайней мере интерсубъективным), смотрите практичнее: для привлечения большего количества людей для решения вопроса необходимо, например, поощрять людей каким-нибудь способом (как и происходит на данном ресурсе), так как сам автор вопроса редко когда напишет "спасибо" на ответ, то весьма нормально то, что введена система баллов и ими поощраются правильные ответы. А вот ваши комментарии в таком стиле, как раз, заставляют задуматься о том, что даже здесь иногда обитают "быдло" :(

Comment: @StateItPrimitive не хочу всё это превращать в чат, а лишь напишу, что   как раз таки тех, кто пишет "Спасибо", "Благодарю" и прочие слова благодарности во много раз больше, чем тех, кто поставит ту же галочку зеленую)

Comment: Я прихожу на SO ради фарма репы и нисколько этого не стыжусь. Зарабатывать виртуальные фантики на SO — полезнее, чем зарабатывать виртуальные фантики в WoW, например. Ну и мне жутко интересно, где вы вообще на Ru.SO видели сложные вопросы. Влад пишет сложные ответы на простые вопросы, конечно, но это не считается. :)

Comment: @Ипатьев Еще кажется несколько странным читать что-то про "Bike Shed problem" от человека, чья репутация составляет 100к на en SO, что побуждало вас отвечать на простые вопросы, за которые дают много репутации (т.к. за сложные не получить её по выше описанным причинам), когда у большинства из них уже существовали и другие ответы до вашего?

Comment: Мне вот еще кажется, что репутация решает проблему, которую я часто видел на всяких форумах, которую можно описать следующимм образом: Американский форум: вы задаете вопрос - вам отвечают на него. Еврейский форум: вы задаете вопрос - вам отвечают вопросом на вопрос. Русский форум: вы задаете вопрос - вам долго и упорно объясняют какой вы мудак и идиот.

Answer (score 1):

Внезапно пришло в голову решение, которое может показаться слишком радикальным.

Можно перейти от балансированной (сумма плюсов/минусов как сейчас) к только положительной оценке участников. Т.е. рейтинг (то число, которое показывается вместе с DisplayName участника) составляют исключительно плюсы к вопросам и ответам данного пользователя и очки за принятые ответы.

Помимо очевидного решения проблемы *tactical downvoting* такая система оценки может сделать оценку плохих (неинтересных) вопросов и ответов более объективной, т.к. минусующего не будет смущать, что своими действиями он наносит кому-либо видимый (и при этом накапливаемый) вред.

Такая система оценки видимо снижает геймификацию системы, стремление участников соревноваться за места в рейтинге, но повышает объективность (не уверен, можно ли вообще говорить про объективность суммы субъективных оценок?) оценки полезности вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Идея довольно интересная, но, как я понял, в ней остается возможность минусовать ответ (тем самым никак не влияя на рейтинг, правда, на самом деле, и сейчас каждый минус вычитает всего 2 единицы рейтинга, что не особо критично), т.е. ответ все равно опустится в общем списке ответов вниз, а ответ 2-го окажется выше и, в итоге, привлечет больше внимания. Я ведь правильно понял идею?)

Comment: Да, на сортировку ответов не повлияет.

Comment: Поддержу в части влияния на рейтинг по меткам - можно было бы его считать только на основании плюсов на ответах, не учитывая минусы. На репутацию минусы и так почти что не влияют.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, в принципе, сортировку ответов тоже можно делать только по плюсам, а не по сумме, но тут я сам сомневаюсь, что это правильно.

Answer (score -1):

А нельзя  ли это отловить программно:
Сделать счетчик, сколько раз кто-то ставил минус на ответ другого пользователя и добавлял свой ответ в тот же вопрос, и если перейдет пороговое значение — сообщить об этом модераторам?

Comment: И что в этом случае должны сделать модераторы?

Comment: @PashaPash, посмотреть на вопросы, может он снижал оценки действительно неправильным ответам. Если нет, то взять его на заметку и плюсовать правильные ответы, которым он понизил рейтинг, а ему придумать какое-то наказание. О! Еще можно записать его в список «неспортивно-ведущих-себя» и впредь отменять его минусы программно.

Comment: ни я, ни другие модераторы не могут "взять и отменить" минусы. и тем более - не могут взять и запретить пользователю ставить минусы только за то, что он их ставит. Многие топовые пользователи активно минусуют ([enSO](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/440087/most-evil-users) / [ruSO](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/440087/most-evil-users). По сути, ваша система будет наказывать пользователя за то, что он минусанул плохой (с его точки зрения) ответ и написал хороший. Минусануть то, что он хочет - его неотъемлемое право.