# Почему бы не оставлять вопросы с учебными задачами

Tags: обсуждение, учебные-материалы, домашки

#### Предпосылка для данного вопроса:

Недавно у меня дети стали изучать программирование.
При попытке поиска задач по программированию, столкнулся с проблемой, что в поисковой выдаче можно найти не так уж много примеров с первого раза.
Многие задачи дублируются, многие древние и одни и те же.

> Понятно, что если очень упорно и долго искать, то можно найти.

#### Возник вопрос-предложение:

Почему бы, вместо удаления, такие вопросы не маркировать специальным образом и оставлять в базе знаний?

**Допустим:**

Создаем 2 метки: учебная задача и конкурсная/олимпийская задача.
При появлении такого вопроса, его переводить в режим "Только чтение" и маркировать метками(допустим: учебная массивы).

В данном случае наполнится база знаний по заданиям, где можно будет поискать разные учебные или конкурсные задания, которые можно решать для себя(или соседа).

Например хочется потренировать мозг или просто скучно, фильтруешь вопросы с олимпийскими задачами и пытаешься их решить.

**Тему можно развить:**

- Вариант установки сниппетов и проверки кода, не знаю, на сколько правильный и возможный...
- Задачам, коллегиально, присваивать некую сложность(от 0 до 10 к примеру)
- К таким вопросам, допустим, можно добавлять варианты решений, которые, например отображаются через Х дней после "подписки" на задачу.
- Или показывать ответы сразу...
- Не засчитывать в репутацию лайки и дизлайки за вопросы и ответы, а использовать их просто для ранжирования полезности(будет справедливо с точки зрения правил SO про учебные задания).

> Тут, конечно, палка о двух концах.

**С одной стороны**, SO сделан для помощи другим, кто пытался разобраться с проблемой. Просто публикация задачи, без попытки решения, говорит, что автор не пытался решить задачу самостоятельно.
**С другой стороны**, SO это база знаний, в таком случае, почему не может быть базы знаний учебных и олимпийских задач, со способами и примерами их решения?

Читая статью [про SO это ресурс для специалистов или нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2) и ответы, похоже, что такая база знаний, в целом, отвечала бы задачам SO.

> Для тех, кто хотел бы занять себя и покачать свои скилы, такая база знаний была бы очень даже полезна на мой взгляд.

#### Какое ваше мнение на эту тему?

Comment: Больная тема. Несколько раз обсуждали, только немного с другой стороны: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10100/339283

Comment: "*переводить в режим "Только чтение"*" --- как переводить? Кто должен переводить? Какие для этого механизмы есть (никаких). А кто отвечать тогда должен на вопрос?

Comment: Идея здравая (если отбросить дополнительные требования, нуждающиеся в не существующих механизмах), но закрывашки ее на корню загубят

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Об изменении какого-то технического аспекта сайта писать надо на MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/ на английском языке. Здесь мы такие вопросы, к сожалению, решить не можем, обсуждение пройдёт впустую.

А о том, оставлять или не оставлять на сайте вопросы домашки и как реагировать на  олимпиадные [олимпиада](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0) задачи и прочие соревнования [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [конкурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Bounties) уже есть несколько вопросов:

- [Что если нам блокировать олимпиадные задачи на неделю?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9660/176217)
- [Код-гольф или любое другое соревнование - это не конкурс](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11166/176217)
- [Удалить метку [учебное-задание]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358/176217)
- [Возвращение причины закрытия вопросов «учебные задания»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10100/176217)

Ну и отдельно поиском можно пройтись:

- [домашка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%20is%3Aq)
- [учебное задание](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20is%3Aq)